# Using an int as an NSDictionary key?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to access my dictionary object. Here's my code:

```
int tag = object.tag;
CGPoint point = [[self.dict objectForKey:tag] CGPointValue];
```

The problem is objectForKey is supposed to take an Objective-C object, not an int. I tried wrapping tag into an NSNumber with `[NSNumber numberWithInt:tag]` and passing that into `objectForKey:` but it returns a null object.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: How did you put the objects into `self.dict` in the first place?

Comment: initWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1,2)], @"100", etc. Note that my dictionary is fine, I'm accessing it in other parts of my code with a for-in (for id key in self.dict) loop. However in this instance I don't want to use a loop. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using numbers as strings for dictionary keys, you should turn the `int` into a `NSString` or `NSNumber` to use it as a dictionary key. Here's how to do it for a string:

```
  NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInteger];
```

As @Hughes BR mentions in a comment, the requirement for the key object is that it must conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: Hi, I manually set my object.tag to be 100, 101, etc. The dictionary keys are written as @"101". Note that I have accessed the dictionary successfully in other parts of my code, specifically when I used a for-in loop. My dictionary objects and keys are all there.

Comment: You needn't use a string. An `NSNumber` would suffice and would potentially be a more natural fit. `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[object tag]]` would do the trick.

Comment: @SedateAlien That's true; if all keys are ints, then NSNumber is better because it's a more specific data type. Then, any attempt to create an NSNumber from the wrong type of data would make it easy to locate the problem.

Comment: @SedateAlien, That's generally correct, but it's worth pointing out that for key-value coding (e.g. storing in `NSUserDefaults`), the key of the `NSDictionary` must be an `NSString`.

Comment: According to the doc, it's any object that respond to nscopying protocol. so nsnumber is fine. dict[@(1)] will work

Comment: `@(myInteger)` would be a cleaner choice though

Answer (score 6):

I use NSNumbers without problems, but must avoid the usual `setObject: forKey:` or `setValue: forKey:` methods. That would create a warning.

No warning, however, is created (and the code works as intended) with

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSNumber *key = @1;
id *myObject  = [your code here];
myDict[key]   = myObject;
```

Retrieval is straightforward:

```
myObject = myDict[key];
```